# Trying to use the GET API to retrieve single term with elasticsearch and the JAVA API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch but I am very close to getting the term, but I'm missing some small detail and I can't figure out what it is.

```
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest("registered", "users", id);
            client.get(getRequest);

            getRequest.storedFields("age"); 
            GetResponse getResponse = client.get(getRequest);
            String pw = getResponse.getField("age").getValue();
            writer.println(getRequest);
```

When I try to run the above code I get a "nullPointerException". I have looked over the doc for the GET API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-get.html but am getting nowhere. Any help someone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose of these two lines in the code ?

```
client.get(getRequest);
getRequest.storedFields("age");
```

I think this might be causing issues